# React-Toastify not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-toastify

I am currently using React-Toastify version 7.0.3 and have upgraded to 9.0.3. But with the updated version I am unable to render any notifcations as all.

Steps I did:

1. yarn add react-toastify@9.0.3
2. Changed Notification file

```
import React from "react";
import { ToastContainer, toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
const ReactToastify = require("react-toastify");
/**
 * 
 * @param {severity, title, message} params 
 */
export const toastnotify = (params) => {
    switch (params.severity) {
        case "success":
            toast.success(params.message,
                {
                    position: "top-right",
                    autoClose: 3000,
                    hideProgressBar: false,
                    closeOnClick: true,
                    pauseOnHover: true,
                    draggable: true,
                    progress: undefined,
                    theme: "light",
                });
            break;
        case "critical":
            toast.error(params.message, {
                position: "top-right",
                autoClose: 3000,
                hideProgressBar: false,
                closeOnClick: true,
                pauseOnHover: true,
                draggable: true,
                progress: undefined,
                theme: "light",
            });
            break;
        case "warning":
            toast.warn(params.message, {
                position: "top-right",
                autoClose: 3000,
                hideProgressBar: false,
                closeOnClick: true,
                pauseOnHover: true,
                draggable: true,
                progress: undefined,
                theme: "light",
            });
            break;
        default: toast(params.message);
            break;
    }
};
export const ToastNotificationsContainer = (props) => {
    return (
        <ToastContainer
            position="top-right"
            autoClose={3000}
            hideProgressBar={false}
            newestOnTop={false}
            closeOnClick
            rtl={false}
            pauseOnFocusLoss
            draggable
            pauseOnHover
            theme="light" />);
};
export const NotificationContainer = (props) => {
    return (<ReactToastify.ToastContainer
        hideProgressBar={true}
        autoClose={3000}
        closeOnClick={true}
        closeButton={false}
        newestOnTop={true}
        position="top-right"
        toastClassName="toast-notification-wrap" />);
};
```

3. In App.js,

```
import { NotificationContainer } from "./shared/Notifications/notifications";
render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <AppHeader />
        <NotificationContainer/>
        <AppSidebar>
        </AppSidebar>
        <AppFooter />
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
```

4. While trying to use the notification,

```
import { toastnotify } from "../../shared/Notifications/notifications";

//Inside function
toastnotify({ severity: "critical", title: "Unable to fetch log details" })
```

I have followed the documentation, but not sure what went wrong. The only difference between the code base is the notifcation.js. The 7.0.3 's notifcations.js file had

```
import { Notification } from '@scuf/common';
import './notifications.scss';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

const ReactToastify =  require('react-toastify');
/**
 * 
 * @param {severity, title, message} params 
 */
export const toastnotify = (params) => {
    ReactToastify.toast(
        <Notification
            hasIcon={true}
            className="toast-notification"
            severity={params.severity}
            title={params.title}
        >
            {params.message || ""}
        </Notification>
    )
}

export const NotificationContainer = (props) => {
    return(
        <ReactToastify.ToastContainer
            hideProgressBar={true}
            autoClose={12000}
            closeOnClick={true}
            closeButton={false}
            newestOnTop={true}
            position="bottom-right"
            toastClassName="toast-notification-wrap"
        />
    )
}
```

Please do let me know if I have missed a step in betwen or the modification is incorrect?

Comment: Generally speaking, you should expect breaking changes when changing major versions of any library and use caution when doing so. You may need to first upgrade to [v8 following the migration docs](https://fkhadra.github.io/react-toastify/migration-v8) and then [migrate to v9](https://fkhadra.github.io/react-toastify/migration-v9/).

Answer (score 0):

You can check in "Issues" of the React-Toastify repo... there is a guy who has the same issue, try to use the 9.1.2 version.

More details about this on the https://github.com/fkhadra/react-toastify/issues/961